# How to redirect on YouTube in Android?

Tags: android

```
public class MovieDescription extends Activity {

Vibrator  vibrator;
TextView tv_title,tv_year,tv_banner,tv_desc;
RatingBar ratingBar;
ImageView iv_watch,iv_poster;
private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "Demo";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";
private static final String TAG_YEAR = "year";
private static final String TAG_RATING = "rating";
private static final String TAG_BANNER= "category";
private static final String TAG_DESC = "description";
private static final String TAG_URL = "url";
private static final String TAG_POSTER = "poster";
     String id,title,year,rating,banner,description,poster, movieUrl;
static JSONArray contacts = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.movie_description);
    initialize();



    String movieDescUrl = "http://vaibhavtech.com/work/android/movie_description.php?id="+MainActivity.movie_Id;

    MovieDescriptionParser jParser = new MovieDescriptionParser();
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(movieDescUrl);

    try {
contacts = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);
        for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) 
        {
            /**********************************Value Parse FromUrl**********************************/
            JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
             id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
             title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
             year = c.getString(TAG_YEAR);
             rating = c.getString(TAG_RATING);
             banner=c.getString(TAG_BANNER);
             description = c.getString(TAG_DESC);
            movieUrl = c.getString(TAG_URL);
             poster = c.getString(TAG_POSTER);
            /**********************************Valeu Assing to UI Component**********************************/

            Log.i(id, title);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    tv_title.setText(title);
    tv_year.setText(year);
    tv_banner.setText(banner);
    tv_desc.setText(description);
    Float rat=Float.parseFloat(rating);
    ratingBar.setRating(rat);

    Bitmap bimage=  getBitmapFromURL("http://vaibhavtech.com/work/android/admin/upload/"+poster);
    iv_poster.setImageBitmap(bimage);

    iv_watch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            vibrator.vibrate(40);
            LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
            View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.customtoast,(ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_layout));
            Toast toast=new Toast(getApplicationContext());
            toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
            toast.setView(view);
            toast.show();
            Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(movieUrl));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    Log.i("Device Versoin is", ""+currentapiVersion);
    if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
} 

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    case R.id.home:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        Log.i("Home", "Press");
        return true;

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void initialize()
{
    tv_banner=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_movie_description_banner);
    tv_desc=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_movie_description_decription);
    tv_title=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_movie_description_name);
    tv_year=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_movie_description_year);
    ratingBar=(RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);
    iv_watch=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_movie_description_watch);
    iv_poster=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_movie_description_poster);
    vibrator=(Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);;
}
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    try {
        Log.i("src",src);
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        Log.i("Bitmap","returned");
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Exception",e.getMessage());
        return null;
       }
    }
 }
```

When I am clicking on "watch now" button it's giving me four options - by mozilz, by Chrome, by YouTube. I want that when I click on watch now button it get redirect on YouTube url link. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
Intent i = app.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.youtube");
if (i != null) 
app.startActivity(i);
```

Check this link also : [Redirect YouTube in Android](http://it-ride.blogspot.in/2010/04/android-youtube-intent.html)

Hope this helps.